# Can´t display images from byte array in a table on AngularJS

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs

I want to display images stored in database, the images are in byte array format.

foto_dis is the image in byte array format.
Im getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL at the image ng-src line.

The code i had for the controller:

```
public JsonResult Get_discos()
        {
            DataSet ds = dblayer.Bindgrid();
            // Se crear una referencia a JavaScriptSerializer
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //Se cambia el Length directo a nuestra referencia
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;


            List<Disco_Model> listdisco = new List<Disco_Model>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                listdisco.Add(new Disco_Model

                {

                    id_dis = dr["id_dis"].ToString(),
                    nombre_dis = dr["nombre_dis"].ToString(),
                    ano_dis = dr["ano_dis"].ToString(),
                    genero_dis = dr["genero_dis"].ToString(),
                    foto_dis = (byte[])dr["foto_dis"],
                    nombre_art_dis = dr["FK_nombre_art_dis"].ToString()

                });           
                    }
            var json = Json(listdisco, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            json.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;
            return json;
        }
```

My code for the table in the html:

```
<body ng-app="GrillaDiscos">

    <div ng-controller="HomeController">

        <table class="tableData">

            <tr>

                <th>ID Disco</th>

                <th>Nombre Disco</th>

                <th>Año Disco</th>

                <th>Genero Disco</th>

                <th>Foto Disco</th>

                <th>Nombre Artista Disco</th>

            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="e in discosdata" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">

                <td>{{e.id_dis}}</td>

                <td>{{e.nombre_dis}}</td>

                <td>{{e.ano_dis}}</td>

                <td>{{e.genero_dis}}</td>

                <td>
                <img ng-src="data:image/PNG;charset=utf-8;base64,{{e.foto_dis}}" />
                </td>

                <td>{{e.nombre_art_dis}}</td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/AngularController/Grilla_Discos.js"></script>

</body>
```

My Javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('GrillaDiscos', []);

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/Home/Get_discos').then(function (d) {

        $scope.discosdata = d.data;
    }, function (error) {

        alert('Failed' + error);
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you missing a sanitization filter for data to not be marked as unsafe? this should go in your app. config.  
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ftp|blob):|data:image\//);

see : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#aHrefSanitizationWhitelist

Comment: @SubodhWasankar Gonna try this. Didnt know that angular blocks type of files.

Comment: I think Base64 is a string.  Are you missing byte-to-base64 conversion?

Comment: @pcalkins I changed the type of data and it worked! thank you so much.